# Ireport new dataset

Tags: dataset, ireport

I am making a report on **ireport 4.6.0** and i want to add a new dataset to use another query , there is no problem with adding a new dataset but when i try to use the new filed in the new dataset in the report the result will be -> **" field Not Found !! "**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have checked **Automatically Retrieve Fields** check box in your iReport query designer else you can manually click on **Read Fields** button. The purpose of either of these processes is, they automatically create the selected columns in your query as iReport fields. 
Or Manually adding the missing fields declaration should also work.
Hope this helps.